# Mostrar un elemento del menú de forma programática, no entiendo por qué en un caso específico el menú es nulo

Tags: android, android-layout

En mi App tengo un botón que activa la reproducción de voz. Estoy optimizando para que dicho botón se muestre solamente si hay texto para leer, ya que antes no tenía ese control y la app hacía crash si en el textView no había nada.

Seguí los siguientes pasos y me funciona en todas las activity, menos en una:

### Uno

Creo un campo del tipo `Menu` en la clase:

```
private Menu menu;
```

### Dos

Asigno el recurso a `menu` en el método `onCreateOptionsMenu()`:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    this.menu = menu;
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

### Tres

Muestro el elemento de forma programática al haber verificado que el `StringBuilder` que recoge los datos no está vacío:

```
        if (sbReader.length()>0) {
            menu.findItem(R.id.item_voz).setVisible(true);
        }
```

Lo he hecho así en más de 10 activitys y funciona, pero hay una donde no funciona, dándome este error:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.deiverbum.app/org.deiverbum.app.activities.OtrasOracionesActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.MenuItem android.view.Menu.findItem(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(Unknown Source:524)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(Unknown Source:37)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Unknown Source:80)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:21)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Unknown Source:152)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(Unknown Source:65)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Unknown Source:11)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Unknown Source:338)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.MenuItem android.view.Menu.findItem(int)' on a null object reference
        at org.deiverbum.app.activities.OtrasOracionesActivity.onCreate(OtrasOracionesActivity.java:121)
```

La línea del error es esta:

```
            menu.findItem(R.id.item_voz).setVisible(true);
```

No es problema del layout del menú, el cual está definido así:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".activities.BreviarioActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/item_voz"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_play"
    android:visible="false"
    android:title="@string/leer"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/item_calendario"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_calendar_toolbar"
    android:title="@string/all_calendar"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

Si por ejemplo quito esto:

```
android:visible="false"
```

el elemento se muestra sin problemas. La cuestión es que me lo reconoce como nulo cuando intento hacerlo visible de forma programática.

¿Alguna idea donde pueda mirar para descubrir por qué en una activity en específico no funciona?

Answer (score 0):

Solo agrega la validación de que el menú no sea nulo de esta manera:

```
if (menu != null && sbReader.length()>0) {
            menu.findItem(R.id.item_voz).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

y Cambia la propiedad visible por:

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Así se evita el crash de la App, pero el problema no queda resuelto, porque `R.id.item_voz` no se hace visible nunca. La idea es hacerlo visible cuando haya texto en el textView, hay texto, pero no se muestra. Esa es la cuestión en las otras Activitys me reconoce a `menu`, pero en esta no y no entiendo por qué. El menú sí está ahí, porque el otro botón (de calendario) se muestra.

Comment: en el xml escribe del item escribe:
android:visibility="gone"

y el if modificalo asi:
if (menu != null && sbReader.length()>0) {
            menu.findItem(R.id.item_voz).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);;
        }

Comment: No sé que pasa realmente, logré hacerlo funcionar así: `@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);
        menu.findItem(R.id.item_voz).setVisible(true);
        return true;
    }` solamente ahí reconoce a `menu`, pero es el objeto del método, tampoco me permite asignarlo a mi variable `private` ni nada, no sé por qué. En las otras Activity en cambio no puedo hacerlo ahí porque no me reconoce los datos que haya en el `StringBuilder`.

Comment: edite mi respuesta ojala te ayude